# How can I show and pagination two queries in the laravel blade?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I want to show **$personnals** and **$users** in a table in the blade.
I know, I have to use **@foreach**. But I can't. Because, I have **two queries** and I can't pagination and show those.

```
$personnals = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('pay_type', 1)
            ->leftJoin('personnels', 'orders.personnel_id', '=', 'personnels.id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'personnels.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select(['name AS personnelName', 'lastname AS personnelLastName'])
            ->get();

 $users = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('pay_type', 1)
        ->leftJoin('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select(['name AS userName', 'lastname AS userLastName', 'orderCode'])
        ->get();
```

$personnals has 100 elements and $users has 100 elements ,too. Every elements is an array. I want to merge these arrays together and have one array with 100 array elements.

For example: I want something like $result:

```
$personnals = [ [ 'a'=>'blue', 'b'=>'red' ], [  'a'=>'green', 'b'=>'black' ] ];
$users = [ [ 'c'=>'yellow', 'd'=>'orange' ], [  'c'=>'white', 'd'=>'pink' ] ];

$result = [
            [ 'a'=>'blue', 'b'=>'red', 'c'=>'yellow', 'd'=>'orange' ] ,
            [  'a'=>'green', 'b'=>'black', 'c'=>'white', 'd'=>'pink' ]
        ];
```

How can I show these in blade with pagination?

OR

Can I show all in one query?How?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read about Laravel's Query Builder's Pagination functionality on Laravel's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination
You may also want to concatenate between those two arrays. You can find how to do it with a quick search about the `array_merge` function.

Comment: I have two query, I can't show these in blade together with foreach.

Comment: You can show those using Blade with `foreach` if you concatenate those two arrays into one array.

Comment: Yes. I use merge_array() , but second array merge after first array, but I want merge together.

Comment: You're not using the `array_merge` function as you should. Please try this code: `$data = array_merge($personnals, $users);`, and use the new created variable `$data` on your `@foreach` loop.

Comment: $personnals has 100 elements and $users has 100 elements ,too. Every elements is an array. I want to merge these arrays together and have one array with 100 elements. Tnx my friend. When I use merge_array,  i have 100*2 element arrays in main array.

Comment: I would recommend you try and learning about Laravel's Eloquent relationships as those are the best practice for your needs (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `union`

```
$personnals = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('pay_type', 1)
            ->leftJoin('personnels', 'orders.personnel_id', '=', 'personnels.id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'personnels.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select(['name', 'lastname', 'orderCode']);


 $result = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('pay_type', 1)
        ->leftJoin('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select(['name', 'lastname', 'orderCode'])
        ->union($personnals)
        ->get();
```

try above!

---

As you want only 100 result instead of 200 than so you are expecting `join` instead of `union`

```
 $result = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('pay_type', 1)
            ->leftJoin('personnels', 'orders.personnel_id', '=', 'personnels.id')
            ->leftJoin('users AS u1', 'personnels.user_id', '=', 'u1.id')
            ->leftJoin('users AS u2', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'u2.id')
           ->select(['u2.name AS userName', 'u2.lastname AS userLastName', 'orderCode', 'u1.name AS personnelName', 'u1.lastname AS personnelLastName'])
            ->get();
```

Comment: Tnx. I use from your cade and I get just 5 results. I use unionAll and I get 200 result. $personnals has 100 elements and $users has 100 elements ,too. Every elements is an array. I want to merge these arrays together and have one array with 100 array elements.

Comment: so, only 100 result but what will be the basis of merge data ?

Comment: For example: I want something like $result:

$personnals = [ [ 'a'=>'blue', 'b'=>'red' ], [  'a'=>'green', 'b'=>'black' ] ];    
$users = [ [ 'c'=>'yellow', 'd'=>'orange' ], [  'c'=>'white', 'd'=>'pink' ] ];     

$result = [
  [ 'a'=>'blue', 'b'=>'red', 'c'=>'yellow', 'd'=>'orange' ] ,
  [  'a'=>'green', 'b'=>'black', 'c'=>'white', 'd'=>'pink' ]
  ];